# Computing face normals on newly created faces

Tags: javascript, three.js, normals, face

I've a simple CricleGeometry in the scene and I'm duplicating its vertices and creating new faces to kind of simulate an extrusion.
After new faces have been created I run the "computeFaceNormals()" but the orientation of them is alternate. How can I have all faces facing outwards?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Here's the main part of the code:

```
//geometry
geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(100, 12);

geometry.mergeVertices();

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffa800 } );


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//CREATE NEW FACES

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


var sideGeo = new THREE.Geometry(); 

//duplicate vertices
for ( var v = 0; v < geometry.vertices.length; v++ ) {

    sideGeo.vertices.push( geometry.vertices[ v ].clone() );
    sideGeo.vertices.push( geometry.vertices[ v ].clone() );

}

//translate every second vertex on Z by 10
for ( var v = 0; v < sideGeo.vertices.length; v += 2 ) {

    sideGeo.vertices[ v ].z += 100;

}

//add them to faces
for ( var v = 0; v < sideGeo.vertices.length -2; v++ ) {

    //vertices IDs
    var a = v;
    var b = v + 1;
    var c = v + 2;

    //add them to a face
    var f = new THREE.Face3(a, b, c);
    sideGeo.faces.push(f);


}

//merge with original geo and compute face normals
geometry.merge(sideGeo);

geometry.computeFaceNormals();


//mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Geometry.computeFaceNormals()`, the orientation of the face normal is determined by the winding order of the vertices of the faces.

In three.js, you need to specify your vertices in counter-clockwise order when looking at the front of the face. In which case, the face normal computed by `computeFaceNormals()` will point at you.

three.js r.75

Comment: What does "three.js r.75" mean?

Comment: @WestLangley You mean when I add them to a face, right?